# Do we need the ability to tag questions "rep-ability"?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

I find 5 [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rep-ability) tagged [rep-ability](/questions/tagged/rep-ability) and am not sure what it means or if it's needed. It seems the tag was later added by a single user. It also has no usage guidance.

Searching for "rep ability" yields 2 real [results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22rep-ability%22), both times used by Jeff Atwood to refer to 20k privileges. With such a meagre result, it seems fair to conclude that its usage never really caught on.

There are already tags covering this, e. g.

- [privileges](/questions/tagged/privileges) (note that "ability" is a tag synonym)
- [trusted-user](/questions/tagged/trusted-user) ("20k" is a tag synonym)
- [moderator-abilities](/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities)
- [10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools)

Having a look at the individual questions tagged [rep-ability](/questions/tagged/rep-ability):

**1) Moderator abilities**

1. [Implement Ratios For Moderation Abilities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1041/implement-ratios-for-moderation-abilities) ([rep-ability](/questions/tagged/rep-ability) doesn't add anything useful, I suggest replace it with [moderator-abilities](/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities))
2. [Make Moderator abilities relate to Rep Inflation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28232/479792) (already has [moderator-abilities](/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities) and [rep-ability](/questions/tagged/rep-ability) can be removed)

**2) Privileges**

1. [Lost my motivation after 3000 points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37066/479792) (I suggest [motivation](/questions/tagged/motivation) and [privileges](/questions/tagged/privileges) (maybe also [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation)) instead of [rep-ability](/questions/tagged/rep-ability))
2. [Bring Back the 200 rep level to not see Sponsored Header Ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24033/479792) (replace it with [privileges](/questions/tagged/privileges))
3. [Delete link missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88181/479792) (this is about 10k abilities, so use [10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools) instead)

**Do you agree with me or do you think that tag is useful (then what should it be used for)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[rep-ability](/questions/tagged/rep-ability) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

Comment: It would be more entertaining if your username was "Community" :P

Answer (score 5):

I am in full support of your idea – it's useless because whatever it means is already covered by the many other tags we have already had on Meta Stack Exchange.

I have edited the only 5 posts as you pointed out, and retagged them with appropriate tags.