# Option to voluntarily *not* reduce ads?

Tags: feature-request, advertising, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [But I don't want “reduced advertising” when I get 200 Rep!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14710/but-i-dont-want-reduced-advertising-when-i-get-200-rep)

I've been benefiting from the questions and answers on Stack Overflow for some time and recently started contributing a little bit myself. I'm not there yet, but I can see that when I hit 200 reputation, I'll earn the "reduce ads" privilege and start seeing fewer banners when I'm logged in.

Is there a way to voluntarily opt out of that privilege (other than logging out)? I know I'm just one user, but I'd like to support Stack Exchange as much as possible for the service they provide. Some of the advertisements in the past have drawn my clicks, and I'd hate to see them lose that revenue (even if it's just one very, very small piece of the pie). I know "less ads" is an incentive to participate, but I haven't been bothered by the level of advertising thus far and wouldn't mind keeping the status quo. For other privileges, I opt out by not using them (e.g. not setting bounties), but as far as I can tell "reduce ads" seems mandatory.