# Can I 'turn off' an unwanted privilege?

Tags: support, privileges, advertising

I am somewhat close to 200 reputation in StackOverflow, which means some ads will be [automatically turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads). Some of these ads are relevant to my interests, and I'd rather have the option to toggle.

Comment: Logout and you'll get the ads back.

Comment: A feature to allow you to turn them off has been proposed before: [But I don't want “reduced advertising” when I get 200 Rep!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14710/but-i-dont-want-reduced-advertising-when-i-get-200-rep).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you can't "turn off" a privilege same way you can't turn off your reputation or badges.

Best work around I can think about is using two browser sessions, one where you are logged in, and one where you are logged out. Use the logged out session to browse the posts, and if you see something  that requires your account (e.g. voting, editing, etc) switch to the other browser.

Comment: There's also [a user script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14718/165581) that can do this (from the post psubsee linked above).

Comment: @abby can you verify it's still working? Lots of JavaScript/DOM can change in 5 years and break such things... (and personally I'm not using any user scripts)

Comment: Erm... no idea. I'm not using it either (and I just found out about it 9 minutes ago).

Comment: Well, if someone will verify it's still working it's worth mentioning in the answer as well. Thanks!