# All your sites are full with ads from a company I'm not interested in. Can I somehow turn them off?

Tags: discussion, advertising, microsoft

As example:

[image]

(Originally from the main page of the [Android SE](https://android.stackexchange.com))

However, I am not really interested in Microsoft's products, and their *flashing*<sup>1</sup> things about their latest, most wonderful offers are annoying me.

Using the "mute" feature of the Google ads, I reported them as "not interested", but it has no effect.

Can I somehow turn them off, but only them, without setting my adblocker? Your other offers (jobs, HNQ, etc) are to me okay.

Maybe it would require some Google settings?

<sub>P.s. If at least they would be static images... or they wouldn't do it so agressively... then this post hadn't been ever created.</sub>

<sup>1</sup><sub>Actually, not the ads are flashing, but they are loaded dynamically by some JS (coming probably from Google). This delayed appearance looks like an animation. The images are static.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Update: My adblocker plugin became somehow... ancient. After a refresh, all problem solved.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However, I am not really interested in Microsoft's products, and their flashing things about their latest, most wonderful offers are annoying me.

Stack Exchange doesn't accept animated ads:

> - All ads must be static image files (no animation) with a max file size of 40k ([source](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising/solutions/ad-banners))

If you're seeing an animated ad served by Stack Exchange, you should report it.  But that seems unlikely, because:

> - Creative should be sent for approval 5 business days prior to campaign launch
> - Third-party ads will be approved on a case-by-case basis  (ibid)

I refreshed the home page on Android several times and couldn't reproduce your report.  Also, all the ads I saw were in English.

Comment: I am not very sure about this, these were google ads. I am not sure if the SE even has an option to influence them. Now I can't see any flashing. But I accept your answer until reproduction.

Comment: If the ads are coming from Google, then SE doesn't control them.  How would SE be able to do something to let you turn them off?

Comment: I've checked it again. The ads doesn't animate, that is true, but they are opened by some javascript (coming probably from the google). It happens some seconds after the page loading (and rendering). This delayed appearance looks as an animation, and yes even this significantly increases the annoyance. I edited it into the post.

Comment: I don't know its details. I suspect, the Googles AI heuristics might also influence, which ads appears where (and, for who). Lately they find quite well the companies/technologies I most dislike (not only the ms), but I am working with technologies/areas on the same field. Their chance for me to click these ads is zero, but it seems they are trying quite vehemently. I also suspect, probably also the SE has some influence, which ads they want to show, and also the advertising companies have some influence, where do they want to advertise. But I don't know the details, so I wrote this post.

Answer (score 9):

You are seeing a full quota of ads on the Android site because [you currently have a reputation of 179](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/50837/peterh) there, which falls short of their [reduce ads privilege](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) that kicks in at 200.

Once you reach a reputation of 200 you are able to [Choose to see reduced ads or not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273652/choose-to-see-reduced-ads-or-not).

Comment: Over 200, there are still ads on the right block. Only the ads on the top disappear. It wouldn't be a problem, if they would be static images, but they are not. It is *annoying*.

Comment: @peterh In my experience, once you have 200 rep, you only see in-house or Community Promotion Ads in the sidebar.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog Thanks! I will be soon 200. :-)

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog Android SE 200 done :-)